# cocos2d game reset problem

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a cocos2d game, and after I exit the game and start it again, it starts at the exact same point it was before closing.why this is happening??and not only this, my game is landscapemode but when i start it again from simulator it comes in potrait mode,not it landscapemode like first time.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Anyone will come to rescue me???

Comment: By pressing the back button of simulator/iPhone.

Comment: Ok, i got a solution. when i press the back button in simulator applicationWillResignActive function is called.So i add the follwing command here-       exit(0); .So i when i press back button the appliction exit.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 4.0, there are new options for "info.plist" file.
If you do not want to add multi-tasking(running in background), just add it.
You can add the option by just clicking and checking in your game project's "info.plist".

And rotation setting is on your "RootViewController.m" file.
You can change your app direction by just changing return value.

I hope your game will work well.

Comment: What option should i add in my info.plis??And how to do it??will you please explain.I found my DidApplicationfinishlaunching not called when i restart the game and thats why the game state not changed.And i also found when i press the back button in simulator applicationWillResignActive function is called.So i set a exception (like division by zero) here so that when i press it the application crash and if i restart it now from simulator it comes from initial state which i want.But i know its not a good solution.So will you explain me how do it correctly.

Comment: Add "Application does not run in background" and check the box by right clicking in your plist and choosing Add Row.